# Retrieve time format to convert to seconds in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, lubridate

I have two different data sets. One uses the time format as `m:s` and the other uses `h:m:s`. I have a workaround to find out which data set I am working with, however I would like to know if there is a straightforward way to retrieve the time format and then convert it to seconds?

I am using **lubridate** as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

a <- c("00:01","00:03","00:05")
b <- c("00:00:01","00:00:03","00:00:05")

a %>% 
  ms() %>% 
  period_to_seconds()

b %>% 
  hms() %>% 
  period_to_seconds()
```

My expectation is that I could somehow retrieve the format, and then based on that either apply `lubridate::ms()` or `lubridate::hms()`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think with the first one, you paste `"00"` at the beginning and then use a single function

Comment: the problem is that I want to automatically detect it. This is part of a shiny app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the input vector have only a single format, create a condition to check if the number of characters are '5', then `paste` '00:' at the beginnng and then apply only `hms` to convert to time format

```
f1 <- function(vec) {
      if(all(nchar(vec)==5)) { 
        vec <- paste0("00:", vec)
       }
        vec %>%
           hms() %>%
           period_to_seconds()

}

f1(a)
#[1] 1 3 5
f1(b)
#[1] 1 3 5
```